# Can this code be shortened?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This is an equation to check whether 1 of the 3 elements has value. If yes, all elements must have a value:

```
if(   (a!='' || b!='' || c!='')   &&   (a=='' || b=='' || c=='')   )
    alert('Please fill all elements');
```

Comment: ternary operator?

Comment: Filter [a,b,c] on empty - length ==0 or 3

Comment: Why would you want to shorten it?

Comment: I guess this is fine. There is nothing wrong in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the modulo operator, making this a solution for 4, 5, or more variables as well -- just adapt the final number:

```
if ((!a+!b+!c)%3)
```

The `!` (a boolean negation) makes `!a` a boolean result, based on the fact that an empty string is falsy, while non-empty strings are truthy, so you get `true` or `false` in these cases respectively.

Booleans are coerced to numbers (0 or 1) when added up. So the sum is either 0, 1, 2, or 3.

The `%` operator gives the remainder after division by 3, which for the possible values is the original value *except* for 3: in that case the result is 0. So we get a non-zero value for, and only for, the cases where we want to show a validation error.

In the context of an `if` condition this value is coerced to a boolean value, and non-zero numerical values are truthy.

#### Dynamic number of inputs

If you have an array of inputs, then you can use a similar pattern with `filter`:

```
// Assume arr = [a,b,c];
if ( arr.filter(Boolean).length%arr.length )
```

Note how the `Boolean` function is used to essentially do the same as the double negation did (actually, it would be the same if I had used `!!` instead of `!` earlier on -- now it gives the opposite boolean value, but that works just as well).

#### Afterthoughts

Although this answers your question, you should really ask yourself if it is worth it to reduce code that much: readable code is a much more important asset than shorter code, certainly when execution time is not influenced by it.

Comment: Oi, clever! Requires a clarifying comment though :-)

Comment: This is how you create unreadable code. I'd suggest you use `Array.prototype.reduce` to create a function that checks the above condition for an arbitrary number of array elements

Comment: `someNotAllEmpty() { return !!(arr.reduce((ac, cv) => ac + !!cv, 0) % arr.length) }`

Comment: @connexo, that sounds like an answer. As you already answered, why not add this to your answer? My intent is to stick to the question (shorter code), while creating a function will make it longer. I agree that looking for shorter code does not often lead to readability, but that was not the question, nor was the question to have a more generic solution. Still I added a paragraph about the readability-concern in my answer.

Comment: As I don't want to steal your approach, I'm not adding this to my answer. IMHO, It would make your approach a much more worthwhile one, though.

Comment: I added a `filter(Boolean)` version instead.

Comment: Thank you. Its brilliant! I don't care bout readable. I just want to know is there a way to shorten the logic. Never thought to use %

Comment: Looking back I note that instead of `!!` it works equally well with just one `!`. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

This may not seem shorter for 3 variables, but it definitely is for a greater number:

```js
let a = "test",
  b = "",
  c = "";
let arr = [a, b, c]
let filteredArr = arr.filter(item => item === '')
if (filteredArr.length > 0 && filteredArr.length < arr.length) {
  alert('Please fill all elements');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
if([a,b,c].find(entry => entry == '').length && [a,b,c].find(entry => entry !== '').length) {
     alert('Please fill all elements');
}
```

IMO is more readable as well, it first checks if any is empty, if so it check if any has data, and if both is true, asks to fill all elements

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(!( !!a === !!b && !!b === !!c))
```

That should do it. Basically this fails if all three conditions are equally truthy or falsy.

Comment: wow..i've never use double !!. Basicly it's a NOT NOT? hmm.. will study this. thx

Answer (score 0):

So, some elements are empty, but not all elements are empty?

```
const emptyCount = (a=='') + (b=='') + (c=='');
if (emptyCount > 0 && emptyCount != 3) {
    alert('Please fill all elements');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do like

```
if (a === "" || b === "" || c === ""){
  alert('Please fill all elements');
}
```